# Problem With Jaw Movement

Tags: animation, rigging

I've been tasked with creating this talking donkey character for a commercial I'm working on.  I've got the basic motion capture stuff figured out (still need to fine tune) but I am stumped when it comes to getting the mouth to open and close properly!  In a previous save file I managed to get it to work after the model creator help me BUT I can't seem to replicate the function after I started with a new rig (based off a motion capture).  I need the lower jaw to open and close as if talking.  The model has a few different objects in it.  The body/face & the jaw with teeth.  I can make the jaw move with a bone and move with the whole body but I can't get it to deform the face when it raises and lowers.  I know I'm missing something very basic (as a background, this is my first attempt at using blender and learning it as I go...not ideal but such is life)
I can provide a link to the files if anyone would care to take a peek under the hood?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To better clarify (per bot suggestion) I need someone to look at my model rigging and tell me what I've got incorrect so I can better animate it.